# How create this slider with Smart Slider in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I need to create a slider with static content and background image changing. I am a beginner with smart slider 3 and I do not understand how to do this. Thank you.

https://smartslider3.com/static/?_ga=2.228986332.1920840806.1525981065-2091538776.1525720374

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all of your images as slide to your slider. Then you just need to add a static slide and put your texts to the static slide.

So your images which switch in the background and you will see the layers on your static slide in the foreground.

Here you can see more examples for static slides: https://smartslider3.com/tag/static-slide/

Comment: @MikeC If this answer solved your issue, please accept the answer by awarding the green tick.  If you still require support, please explain to Roland exactly what is left to resolve.  Abandoned pages are much less valuable/reliable than resolved pages. Please do your part to make StackOverflow a great resource.